# How to get work with Jquery tageditor control?

Tags: jquery

I am using **jquery tag editor** in my Jsp page.

It shows the following error in Developer console of browser and doesn't work in jsp page.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; >> for jquery-1.4.2.min.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined >> for jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js
```

My code in Jsp is as follows,

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.autoGrowInput.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tagedit.js"></script>
</head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
    // Empty List
        $('input.tag').tagedit({
            // autocompleteURL: 'path/to/your/server' 
        });
});

</script>
 function fieldValidation(){
   var lengthofCtrl = document.getElementsByName("tags[]").length;
alert(lengthofCtrl);
var testvalue="";
    var testLength = lengthofCtrl-1;
    if(testLength > 0){
    for(i=0;i<lengthofCtrl-1;i++){              
        alert(document.getElementsByName("tags[]")[i].value);
        testvalue = document.getElementsByName("tags[]")[i].value;
}        alert(testvalue);
 }

<form>
  <input type="text" name="tags[]" id="testId" value="" class="tag" /> 
  <input type="button" onClick="fieldValidation()" name="add"
    value="Create"    tabindex="3">
</form>
```

Comment: Check it seems your file `js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js` is not loading

Comment: check your js files are loaded in document..